# ZKTeco merge 3 finger print C# with ZKFingerSDK

Tags: c#, zkteco

I have been working on a small application to get fingerprints after 3 scanned. I used the ZKFingerSDK and when trying to get the register finger prints it brings the image back as black. I am using the ZK9500 device

```
if (RegisterCount >= REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT && !bIdentify)
{

    RegisterCount = 0;
    ret = GenerateRegisteredFingerPrint();   // <--- GENERATE FINGERPRINT TEMPLATE


    if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)
    {

        ret = AddTemplateToMemory();        //  <--- LOAD TEMPLATE TO MEMORY
        if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)         // <--- ENROLL SUCCESSFULL
        {
            string fingerPrintTemplate = string.Empty;
            zkfp.Blob2Base64String(newRegTmp, cbCapTmp, ref fingerPrintTemplate);
            newRegTmp =  zkfp.Base64String2Blob(fingerPrintTemplate);

            Bitmap bmp2;
            MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();

                BitmapFormat.GetBitmap(newRegTmp, mfpWidth, mfpHeight, ref ms2);
                bmp2 = new Bitmap(ms2);
                this.pictureBox1.Image = bmp2;


            Console.WriteLine("finger print" + fingerPrintTemplate);
            textRes.AppendText("merged " + fingerPrintTemplate + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is one supposed to get the SDK for the question?

Comment: @Alex you can get the SDK from here:  [link](https://www.zkteco.com/en/search?keywords=ZKFingerSDK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `ret = AddTemplateToMemory();` loads the template into newRegTmp.

`zkfp.Blob2Base64String(newRegTmp, cbCapTmp, ref fingerPrintTemplate);` from this line i understand that you have the rawdata of the fingerprint at newRegTmp and you are extracting the size of cbCapTmp into fingerPrintTemplate.

In that case, you should not use newRegTmp in next line `newRegTmp =zkfp.Base64String2Blob(fingerPrintTemplate);` , which overwrites the actual data with the Base64 string.  You can use Base64 string for displaying image on the web page with img tag. But to convert the raw data into image, you need to pass the actual data to GetBitMap.

If the above suggestion doesnt work, please share the implementation of AddTemplateToMemory.

Comment: This is my implementation:                                                                                 
      `private int GenerateRegisteredFingerPrint()
        {
            return fpInstance.GenerateRegTemplate(RegTmps[0], RegTmps[1], RegTmps[2], newRegTmp, ref cbRegTmp);
        }

        private int AddTemplateToMemory()
        {
            return fpInstance.AddRegTemplate(iFid, newRegTmp);
        }`

Comment: I have added the out put on the question

Comment: You can get the image from every scanning and you can get the merged template out of three scanned data. But, image can not be merged. Only template can be merged.

Comment: can I then save that merged template as a image?

Comment: While you scan the fingerprint , you will get template and a image.  So you will have image for every scanning. If you want to maintain the image, then either you can one of them or all of them. Merged template is not a image. The size of the template would be between 2k-3k, where as image would in 100k+ (png).

Comment: Thank you Ramshri.  How can I load the image back to he devices memory if I have saved the byte array

Comment: Welcome. Just wondering, why do you need to load the image back into scanner memory. You have to use the template alone for the comparison.

Comment: I want to compare the one that was saved previously and stored in my db to the new one scanned to verify the students new finger print with the one from the db

Comment: You need to use the merged template with newly scanned template for the comparison. You can use the images only for display purpose.

Comment: Okay so I can save the merged template to my systems db and then let the user scanned a new one and compare it? if so how will i do it?